# How to update a div of a html page with Firebase database strings from android activity

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I retrieve User Name and email address from Firebase Database as strings in my `htmlActivity`. Is there any way that I can send these two strings inside a `div` of my `index.html` that is displayed inside the WebView component?

There are different examples of sending whole page html data to the WebView component but I want to update just one div of my already designed html page.

This is what I have tried, but it doesn't change the innerHTML from the strings.

My `index.html` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<body>
   <div id="replace1">UserName</div>
   <div id="replace2">Email</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

This is my `htmlActivity`.

```
public class SmartActivity extends Activity implements AdvancedWebView.Listener {
    private AdvancedWebView mWebView;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_smart);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mWebView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/home.html");
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        getUserProfile();
    }

    public void getUserProfile() {
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String userID = user.getUid();
        if (user != null) {
            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
            ref.child(userID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String username = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    String email = user.getEmail();
                    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                        @Override
                        public void onPageFinished(WebView web, String url) {
                            String text1 = "UserName";
                            String text2 = username;
                            web.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('" + text1 + "', '" + text2 + "')})()");
                        }
                    });
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

How can I send these two strings to update the div of the index html with the name and email address of the user?

Comment: Can you tried this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938119/changing-html-in-a-webview-programmatically

Comment: @VijayRajput Thanks. I've tried it and it still doesn't work. I've updated my question what I've done so far.