# How to replace a few lines of code in js file in a WebView?

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

Im loadind URL inside WebView and i need to change one sentence inside js file. I know the name of that file. 
How i can intercept that file, change certain line and put it on.

Right now i just copied url by which this file loaded, and copied that file.
Im comparing all urls and when its true im just replacing this file.
This is not good because js file can change, and my copied file will be out of date.

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            String url = request.getUrl().toString();

            if (url.equals("URL_FILE_WHICH_NEED_TO_REPLACE")) {

                InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.COPIED_FILE_WITH_REPLACED_LINE);

                return new WebResourceResponse("text/js", "UTF-8", is);
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938119/changing-html-in-a-webview-programmatically take a look here may answers help you